# how to read statistics.db and summary.db file in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, statistics, datastax-enterprise

i am trying to read the Statistics.db file and summary.db file but i couldn't read  I want to know what is the data that will be stored in it, any specific format. if so what is the format and what data regarding partition it stores.

how can i convert these .db files to readable format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [great explanation](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html) of SSTables, which include Statistics.db and summary.db files. SSTables are created when a new table space is created. The format of the SSTable is embedded in the file name. In this example, the format is version "ka".

`main_dev-table1-ka-56-Statistics.db`

From the reference:

> In version "ka", contents of Statistics component file is split in to
>   3 types of metadata called validation, compaction and stats.
>   Validation metadata is used to validate SSTable which includes
>   partitioner and bloom filter fp chance fields. Compaction metadata
>   includes ancestors information which is also available in older
>   formats and a new field called cardinality estimator. Cardinality
>   estimator is used to efficiently pre-allocate bloom filter space in a
>   merged compaction file by estimating how much the input SStables
>   overlap. Stats metadata contains rest of the information available in
>   old formats and two additional fields. First one is a flag to track
>   the presence of local/remote counter shards and the other one is for
>   storing the repair time.